# how to install pycurl in windows?

Tags: python, pycurl

```
$ pip install pycurl
Enter file name: form_13_og.py

Collecting pycurl
  Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.6.tar.gz (222 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-install-_4d43014\\pycurl\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\cygwin64\\tmp\\pip-install-_4d43014\\pycurl\\se
tup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-pip-egg-info-c24ci1ko'
         cwd: C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip-install-_4d43014\pycurl\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    Enter file name: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
        __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\extern\__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
        __import__(extant)
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 83, in <module>
        import copy
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\copy.py", line 60, in <module>
        from org.python.core import PyStringMap
      File "c:\users\mandar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\org.py", line 11, in <module>
        fname = input('Enter file name: ')
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this link to install `pycurl` module: [PycURL Installation — PycURL 7.43.0.6 documentation](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html)

You may download the latest version of `pycurl` from [Download Area](https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/) in this link and then try it again.

Comment: There are no official windows packages for 7.43.0.6, the only installation option presently is building from source.

Comment: I think you can download it here: https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/#files